# Access to contents of the selected object in a Django OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I would like to retrieve specific field data from a selected object within a OneToOneField relation. I have three models: Model1 contains the 'malfunction_1' field, which I intend to copy into the 'malfunction_3' field within Model3. Model2 possesses the OneToOneField. When a Model2 object is created and an object is chosen within the OneToOneField, another Model3 object should be generated. The content from 'malfunction_1' (Model1) and 'dynamik_2' (Model2) should then be duplicated into 'malfunction_3' and 'dynamik_3' fields, respectively.

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    malfunction_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)

class Model2(models.Model):
    given_malfunctions = models.OneToOneField(Model1, blank=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    dynamik_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True)


class Model3(models.Model):
    connection_to_model2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    malfunction_3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    dynamik_3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True)
```

would you use a receiver method or define a normal function for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) the save method of `Model2` like this:

```
class Model2(models.Model):
   # rest of the code
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model2, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        Model3.objects.create(
          connection_to_model2=self, malfunction_3=self.given_malfunctions.malfunction_1, dynamik_3=self.dynamik_2
        )
```

But it doesn't make sense why you need `Model3` when you can get all the fields by querying the `Model2` wherever you need `Model3` as that has relations already maintained.